# Google cloud platform "Your free trial has ended" - server no longer available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami

I opened on 2018/1/1 Google's free 1 year trial with bitnami.
got an email 2+ weeks ago saying:

```
Your free trial has ended.

Time has run out, and your free trial is over. After 30 days, your work may 
be deleted. Upgrade now to keep working and gain full access to the 
Google Cloud Platform global infrastructure.
```

I saw a -10.5$ balance - I actually had to pay 13$ (there's a minimum pay)
now I see a balance of 23.5$

now, really, I am confused, all I want is to get the server back up for a few minutes so I can back it up.

Google's support said since my free tier is done I need to pay an extra 100$ to get answered of how to get my site back for a moment

ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps anyone else:
Apparently all I needed to do is log into 
google cloud product -> Compute Engine -> VM Instance
choose my instance and start it

it seems that although there was a minus before my Balance - it's actually a dash, not a minus sign 
got this from Google support